# Aligned equations with comments/explanations

Tags: equations, align, margins, multline

In many cases I want to write some aligned equation that goes through multiple lines and add a comment for some of the lines (I think if the comments are short enough then it's clearer than explaining everything at the end of the equation). Ideally, all the comments should start on the same vertical line. This is achieved by what's shown in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    This is just some text to show where the margin is. Some more and more text yay text is good.
    \begin{align*}
    a + b + c + d + e &= an-expression \\
    &= some-very-longgggggggggg-expression && \text{comment} \\
    &= another-expression && \text{a little longer comment} \\
    &= 0
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The problem is when some of the equation's lines are too long:

[image]

The second comment is inside the right margin, which should not be allowed.

I know it happens because the `align` environment creates a table and each `&` sign adds a column, so the second comment cannot be on a different column than the first comment (which is pushed by the equation on its row).

But still, what I would like to happen is that the second comment would end by the right margin. Is there a simple way to achieve that? If possible, I would prefer to not define too complicated commands, even if it means I'll not get exactly what I asked for, but something else that kinda solves the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Could you provide the definition of the macros you are using, or, better, a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/69818)?

Comment: where is define `\condexp[1]{...}`?

Comment: @GuM, Zarko, Thanks for the feedback. I edited the question, the example is now fully working.

Comment: @Zarko I made a different example which is a MWE like GuM suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling `\lefteqn` from [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464906/175237) I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5588/175237) which is about `\MoveEqLeft` - a command from mathtools (see 3.4.4 [here](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf)). So the example becomes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    This is just some text to show where the margin is. Some more and more text yay text is good.
    \begin{align*}
    \MoveEqLeft[1] a + b + c + d + e \\
    &= an-expression \\
    &= some-very-longgggggggggg-expression && \text{comment} \\
    &= another-expression && \text{a little longer comment} \\
    &= 0
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Which yields the following output (same as egreg's):

[image]

I think this solution is a bit better than using `\lefteqn` since `\MoveEqLeft` was made specifically to solve this problem (according to the documentation).

Comment: That's essentially equivalent, in my opinion. It allows to not add braces.

Comment: @egreg And not to add `\quad`

Comment: Well, `\quad` is a space of 1em, so it is exactly what's done by `\MoveEqLeft[1]`.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot have all the comments vertically aligned at their left margin, because the wide equation and the wide comment simply don't fit the line.

You can save space by setting the first term on a line by itself and still have the look of a display, avoiding to go to the left margin:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

This is just some text to show where the margin is.
Some more and more text yay text is good.
This is just some text to show where the margin is.
Some more and more text yay text is good.
\begin{align*}
\lefteqn{a + b + c + d + e}\quad \\
&= an-expression \\
&= some-very-longgggggggggg-expression && \text{comment} \\
&= another-expression && \text{a little longer comment} \\
&= 0
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

With `\lefteqn` you hide the width of the term; I added `\quad in order not to have the`=` signs at the left margin and it turns out that still a tad of space is available.

[image]

Another possibility you can explore, but this depends on the actual equations and comments, is breaking the long comment across lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

This is just some text to show where the margin is. 
Some more and more text yay text is good.
This is just some text to show where the margin is. 
Some more and more text yay text is good.
\begin{align*}
a + b + c + d + e
&= an-expression \\
&= some-very-longgggggggggg-expression && \text{comment} \\
&= another-expression && \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
                         a little \\
                         longer \\
                         comment
                         \end{tabular} \\
&= 0
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, for my case this is the best solution. Except I've just read about `\MoveEqLeft` and I think it might be a tiny bit better. What do you think? I posted a separate solution that explains it, hope it's OK. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/465987/175237

Answer (score 1):

Well, the following is a very simple trick that “kinda solves the problem”:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath}



\begin{document}

% \slshape % if uncommented, will the reference to the Magic Theorem be slanted?

Some text before the equation, to show where the right margin lies.  Oh, no, 
that was not enough: \emph{now} it is enough!
\begin{flalign*}
    \textit{formula\_result} &= \textit{short\_term} \\
        &= \textit{muuuuch\_loooonger\_term} + \textit{another\_one}
                && \text{by \ldots} && \\
        &= x-x
                && && \makebox[0pt][r]{by the Magic Theorem} \\
        &= 0
\end{flalign*}
Some text after the equation, to show again the position of the right margin of
the text block.

\end{document}
```

This is the output I get (on a TeXLive 2016, sorry, but that’s what I’ve got at the moment):

[image: Output of the code]

**Addition:**
An even simpler solution using `\hidewidth`, which, however, does *not* yield exactly the same printout as the previous one:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath}



\begin{document}

Some text before the equation, to show where the right margin lies.  Oh, no, 
that was not enough: \emph{now} it is enough!
\begin{flalign*}
    \textit{formula\_result} &= \textit{short\_term} \\
        &= \textit{muuuuch\_loooonger\_term} + \textit{another\_one}
                & \text{by \ldots} & \\
        &= x-x
                & \hidewidth\text{by the Magic Theorem} & \\
        &= 0
\end{flalign*}
Some text after the equation, to show again the position of the right margin of
the text block.

\end{document}
```

Indeed, IMHO the output is actually better, with *both* explanations aligned along the right margin:

[image: Output of the second code sample]

**Second addition:**
If you object to using plain TeX commands like `\hidewidth`, you can replace the second example with the following code

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath}



\begin{document}

% \slshape

Some text before the equation, to show where the right margin lies.  Oh, no, 
that was not enough: \emph{now} it is enough!
\begin{flalign*}
    \textit{formula\_result} &= \textit{short\_term} \\
        &= \textit{muuuuch\_loooonger\_term} + \textit{another\_one}
                & \text{by \ldots} & \\
        &= x-x
                & \makebox[0pt][r]{by the Magic Theorem} & \\
        &= 0
\end{flalign*}
Some text after the equation, to show again the position of the right margin of
the text block.

\end{document}
```

with no change in the output.

Comment: You can replace `\hidewidth{\text{...}}` with the simpler `\llap{...}`.

Comment: @Bernard: Yes, but some *very* influential users, here, object against advertising the use of `\llap` to newbies… :-)  Moreover, perhaps a still better solution could be to move the `\hidewidth` to the line of the “muuuch loooonger term”: I guess it depends on the context…

Comment: Of course it has to be used *very* cautiously.

Comment: @Bernard: Well, actually `\llap` *was* the first thing I thought of, but I deliberately rejected it.

Comment: Well, I agree that `\llap` is not for newbies. But `\hidewidth` is for wizards. `;-)`

Comment: @ereg: OK, so we are back to `\makebox[0pt][r]{...}`: full circle… :-)

Comment: Thank you! I tried the solution from your second addition since the output looked very nice. My first comment ends with `2` and my second comment ends with `(2)` and for some reason the aligning of this text specifically looks kinda ugly (or is it just me?) so I guess I'll use it for other cases. See: https://i.imgur.com/V1WGWnL.png

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possibilities, with the `flalign*` environment, and `\mathrlap` from `mathtools`, or with a simple `align*`  and  the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{showframe}
 \renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}

\begin{document}

    This is just some text to show where the margin is. Some more and more text yay text is good.
    \begin{flalign*}
   \mathrlap{ a + b + c + d + e} \\
    &= an-expression \\
    &= some-very-longgggggggggg-expression && \text{comment} \\
    &= another-expression && \text{a little longer comment} \\
    &= 0
    \end{flalign*}
Some other text and another possibility:
\begin{fleqn}
    \begin{align*}
    a + b &+ c + d + e\\
    &= an-expression \\
    &= some-very-longgggggggggg-expression && \text{comment} \\
    &= another-expression && \text{a little longer comment} \\
    &= 0
    \end{align*}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Can you make the lines after the first one a little indented? (without adding some `\quad` on every line)

Comment: I've adde a second possibility with `fleqn`.

Comment: Thank you! The problem with that second solution is that the first expression (`a+b+c+d+e`) is actually the output of a command I created (imagine something like `\mycommand{a+b+c}{d+e}` and it doesn't work to put `&` in there. Sorry for not including that in the question, I tried to create a good MWE. Should I add the exact command?

Comment: @EllaShar: Can you nest the result of your command in another command?

Comment: You mean `\anothercommand{\mycommand{a+b+c}{d+e}}`? Yes. Actually egreg's first solution has the same output as your second solution and it is achieved using nesting.

Comment: In this case, in my 2nd solution, you can replace the first line with something like       `\makebox[2em][l]{$ a + b + c + d + e $}`.

Comment: Great! Do I need `fleq`? I think it works without it the same way.

Comment: `fleqn`  is to ensure the equation starts at the left margin. It is like having the `fleqn` option, but only locally. Maybe  you don't need it because you havea  really long equation, but you can't be sure before you've tried.

Comment: So `flalign*` is the same as `fleqn` in this context?

Comment: Not quite, because `flalign*` supposes there are three alignment groups.

Comment: I'm so confused. The documentation for `flalign` doesn't say anything about 3 groups. http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf

Comment: You're right. I had retained  three alignment groups, probably because that was the example I had seen in a tutorial (long ago…). What's important is there's a group starting at the left margin, and a group ending at the right margin.

Comment: Oh OK. So is it different from `fleqn`?

Comment: `fleqn`makes the left indent of all equations to 0 (or the value you give as an optional argument). It can be use  with `align`, `alignat`, `gather`. It works as a switch (somewhat like the `subequations` environment).